# $R$ Gorenstein implies $\operatorname{Proj}(R)$ Gorenstein

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, gorenstein

Let $k$ be a field and let R be a Gorenstein $k$-algebra which has a non-negative grading $R=\oplus_{k\geq 0} R_k.$ Assume further that $R_0=k$ and that $R$ is generated in degree one. I've seen it asserted without proof that the scheme $\operatorname{Proj}(R)$ is Gorenstein. How does one prove this?

To explain where I'm stuck: I know $\operatorname{Proj}(R)$ is covered by the degree zero pieces of localizations $R_f$ for homogeneous $f$ (these localizations are Gorenstein). However, I don't know why taking degree zero piece preserves Gorensteiness.

Comment: 1: You can and should use MathJax in titles. 2: What have you tried? The fact that localizations of Gorenstein rings are again Gorenstein would seem to be a rather big hint.

Comment: 1: Fixed. 2: I know $\operatorname{Proj}(R)$ is covered by the degree zero pieces of localizations $R_f$. However, I don't know why taking degree zero piece preserves Gorensteiness.

Comment: P.S. Whoever downvoted, you do realize this isn't Mathoverflow right?

Comment: You should put the context you've mentioned in your comment in to your question to help ward off downvotes and votes to close for missing context. While I am not the downvoter, I would imagine the downvote is because this question is nothing else but the statement of a problem, and MSE has a [stated policy to discourage such questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9201/proposal-discourage-questions-that-are-nothing-besides-a-problem-statement).

Comment: Alright fair enough--- but how could I know? It should be evident I'm not exactly a seasoned user of this site and my question is quite clear and not ill-posed (nor homework).

Comment: @mathdonkey Up/downvoting refers to a post, not to a personality. Also, nothing indicates that it is not homework.

Comment: @lisyarus Well, perhaps I'm missing something incredibly stupid but I just don't see it. I'm not an algebraic geometer but work in a neighboring field and need/want to understand this claim.  As for being HW, you do realize that universities are on summer holiday (not mention closed etc)? Even if it were e.g. a graduate AG problem, say Hartshorne (it's not), is that really off-limits?

Comment: @mathdonkey Some universities have gone online, some may have special summer courses, whatever. The point is that low-quality posts are not welcome here, and posts containing only the problem statement are considered low-quality; whether this is from Hartshorne or whether universities are closed is irrelevant.

Comment: (I personally upvoted this, since it is not low-quality after update)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a key lemma which is very important for understanding how Gorenstein-ness can be translated from one situation to another.

> **Lemma** ([Stacks 0BJL](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0BJL)): Let $A\to B$ be a flat local homomorphism of noetherian local rings. The following are equivalent:
>
> 1. $B$ is Gorenstein
> 2. $A$ and $B/m_AB$ are Gorenstein.

Let $S=\{1,f,f^2,\cdots\}$ for $f$ homogeneous of degree one, and consider $S^{-1}R$. We can write $S^{-1}R=(S^{-1}R)_0[f,f^{-1}]$, where I mean "freely adjoining" - I claim that $f$ doesn't satisfy any nonzero polynomial equations with coefficients from $(S^{-1}R)_0$. Suppose $\sum_{i=0}^{i=n} c_if^i$ is such a polynomial and assume $c_n\neq 0$. Then $c_nf^n=0$ by degree reasons, which cannot be the case unless $c_n=0$ in $(S^{-1}R)_0$ already (unwind the definitions of the localization). This implies that the map $(S^{-1}R)_0\to S^{-1}R$ is flat.

Now for any prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ of $S^{-1}R$ lying above a prime ideal $\mathfrak{q}$ of $(S^{-1}R)_0$, we get an induced map of local rings between the localizations. The assumption that $R$ is Gorenstein implies all local rings of $R$ (and thus $S^{-1}R$) are Gorenstein, so all local rings of $(S^{-1}R)_0$ are Gorenstein by the lemma. So $(S^{-1}R)_0$ is Gorenstein, and as the spectra of such rings cover $\operatorname{Proj} R$ as $f$ varies, we have shown that $\operatorname{Proj} R$ is Gorenstein.

Comment: I think the proof is right but the Theorem may be wrong. The claim S^{-1}(R)=(S^{-1}(R))_0[f,f^{-1}]  seems to require $f$ has degree 1, otherwise if f has degree 2 say, the right hand side lives in only even degrees which could miss things in degree 1? So, maybe the Theorem needs the assumption that R is generated in degree 1 (in which case we could cover by D(f) with deg(f)=1.)?

Comment: @mathdonkey Good point, I think you're right. Are you happy with assuming $R$ is generated in degree $1$ so we can pick $f$ of this form, or are you looking for additional discussion about that?

Comment: This is good enough for me. I've changed the question and accepted your answer.